# Does Saitama have enhanced senses?

Tags: one-punch-man

So Saitama jumped and appeared at King's apartment in floor 22th. How did he know King was there? Does Saitama have enhanced vision, hearing or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes he had according to his wikia he possessed the superhuman strength https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Saitama

Immense Senses: Saitama's senses are far beyond the human norm. Nevertheless, Saitama's senses do not have the same degree of 'resolution' as some of Genos' sensors, which can detect and distinguish foes at a greater distance. Even so, he does possess impressively sharp hearing, being able to pick up on various chatter from bystanders a good distance away even while fighting monsters and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I would not be surprised if he has greatly enhanced senses, since he was able to easily track and keep up with Sonic during their first fight. That confirms that he has enhanced vision, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was reading a segment of the webcomic and Saitama is able to see in the dark. Garou is surprised about this, because he thought it would be impossible for a person to distinguish anything where they were fighting, and he asks what kind of vision Saitama has. So, yes, at least Saitama has enhanced vision.